# Computing volume of a set in $\mathbb R^3$

Tags: calculus

Let $\Omega = \{ (x,y,z) : x^2 + y^2 \leq z^2 \leq 4 \} $

So, the problem is to find the volume of this set. MY though: comput

$$ \iiint_{\Omega} dV $$

But, im having trouble seeing the picture of the set, and hence finding limit of integration. Can someone help me? thanks

Comment: Hint:  $0 \leq x^2+y^2 \leq z^2$ describes the region inside a right circular cone.  And hence $0 \leq x^2+y^2 \leq z^2 \leq 4$ describes the region inside two cones (with tips at the origin) bounded by the planes $z=2$, $z=-2$.  You can actually compute the volume of this set without calculus, but it would be good to also try calculating this with an integral.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another way to compute this is using integration.  Since 
$$\Omega = \{(x,y,z)\, | \, x^2+y^2\leq z^2 \leq 4\}$$

Consider the upper cone (in the sense of $z\geq 0$.  Then, on the upper cone, $\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\leq z \leq 2$, $-\sqrt{4-x^2}\leq y \leq \sqrt{4-x^2}$, $-2 \leq x \leq 2$

$$\iiint_{\Omega} \,\text{d}V = 2\int_{-2}^2 \int_{-\sqrt{4-x^2}}^{\sqrt{4-x^2}} \int_{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}^2 1\ \text{d}z\,\text{d}y\,\text{d}x$$

which upon changing to cylindrical coordinates is indeed
$$\iiint_\Omega \text{d}V = 2\int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^2 \int_r^2 r\,\text{d}z\,\text{d}r\,\text{d}\theta = \frac{16\pi}{3}$$

---

Fixed a typo, typing more to allow the edit

Comment: why is $x$ between $-2$ and $x$. I don't understand this part. Would you mind explaning why this is the case? thanks

Comment: Fixed.  Sorry about that.  I meant to write $-2 \leq x \leq 2$, and for whatever reason, didn't catch that when I was proofreading it.

Comment: By the way, since it wasn't entirely clear as written why I did it this way, the factor of $2$ out front is by symmetry.  The bounds we gave will allow you to compute the volume of the region between the planes $z=0$ and $z=2$, but the region is symmetric about the plane $z=0$, so the volume of the region is twice the volume of the upper cone.

Comment: One silly question: Why $r$  is at most $2$? I know it must be positive, but how do you know it is bounded by $2$ ?

Comment: Because $0 \leq x^2 + y^2 \leq z^2 \leq 4$ implies that $0 \leq x^2+y^2 \leq 4$, whence $0 \leq r = \sqrt{x^2+y^2} \leq 2$.  It's not sharp (in the sense that $x^2+y^2 \leq z^2$ is not used at all in this deduction), but we don't need it to find bounds on $r$.

Answer (score 0):

It's a double cone with an axis Z of height 2 and with a radius of  the base 2. Hence $V=2 \pi r^2 \frac{h}{3} = 2\pi*4*\frac{2}{3}=\frac{16}{3}\pi$

Answer (score 0):

Plot the shape to see what's going on. Using the polar coordinates the volume is given by

> $$ V := 2\int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_{0}^{2}\int_{r}^{2} r dzdrd\theta. $$

Here is the shape

[image]

Comment: As written, there is an error in the integral as presented.  (The inner integral should be with respect to $z$, not $r$)

Comment: @NicholasStull: I missed the $dz$. It is corrected. Thanks for the comment.

Comment: why is $r$ between $r$ and $2$ ? I don't get this part :s